# Find $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP = J$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Let $$A =  \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 1 & 0 & -1           \\[0.3em]
      0 & -1 & 1 & 2 \\[0.3em]
      -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{bmatrix}$$

I already found that the Jordan form of $A$ is $$J =  \begin{bmatrix}
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0           \\[0.3em]
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\[0.3em]
      0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix}$$

Now, I wish to find an invertible $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP = J$. I know there are several ways doing it. One way is finding a basis of $V$ consisting linearly independent eigen-vectors.

So $$V_{\lambda=0} = \text{sp}\{(-1,1,1,0)\} \\ V_{\lambda=1} = \text{sp}\{(-1,1,0,1)\} $$

Now, I am lacking of two vectors to complete a basis of $V=\mathbb{R}^4$.

What should I do in this kind of scenario?

Thanks.

**EDIT**
$A$ should be

$$   \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 1 & 0 & -1           \\[0.3em]
      0 & -1 & 1 & 2 \\[0.3em]
      -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Whenever your Jordan form is non-diagonal, it will be impossible to find a basis of eigenvectors.  What you need for the situation are "generalized eigenvectors".

Comment: This cannot be the Jordan form, since the only eigenvalue is $0$ ($\chi_A(x)=x^4$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial (and the minimal polynomial of $A$, as one can check) is $\chi_A(x)=x^4$.

Thus $\ker A^4=\mathbf R^4$. One checks $\DeclareMathOperator{\rk}{rank}\; \rk A=3,\ \rk A^2=2,\ \rk A^3=1 $. Hence the Jordan normal form is:
$$J=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$
To find a change of basis matrix $P$ such that $J=P^{-1}AP$, we have to find a basis of generalised eigenvectors.

For that, we take a vector $v$ that is in $\mathbf R^4\smallsetminus \ker A^3$. As 
$$A^3=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&-1\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix},$$
we see a choice is $\;v_4=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$. Then: $$v_3=Av_4=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\2\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\enspace v_2=Av_3=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix},\enspace\text{and finally} \enspace v_1=Av_2=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
The change of basis matrix is:

$$P=\begin{bmatrix}-1&1&-1&0\\1&-2&2&0\\1&-1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: What theorem this algorithm rely on?

Comment: That's standard. For a nilpotent endomorphism $u$, you have a strictly increasing sequence $0\subsetneq\ker u \subsetneq\ker u^2\subsetneq\dots\subsetneq u^k$ (the sequence stabilises for exponents $>k$, and it is easy to show that for $x\in\ker u^k\smallsetminus\ker u^{k-1}$, the family $x, u(x), u^2(x),\dots,u^{k-1}(x)$  is free.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The eigenvalue $\lambda =0$ has algebraic multiplicity $4$ and only one eigenvector $v_1\ne 0 =(-1,1,1,0)^T$. So you needs three generalized eigenvectors that you can chose as:
$$
v_2=(0,-1,0,0)^T
$$
$$
v_3=(-1,1,0,0)^T
$$
$$
v_4=(-1,1,0,1)^T
$$

Comment: Where did these come from?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the Generalized Eigenvectors of this matrix. See what the algebraic and geometric multiplicities and find the generalized eigenvectors for the ones where the g.m < a.m.

That will give you the full set of basis for $ \mathbb R ^4$.

B.t.w the J matrix you posted is not the same returned by MATLAB.

Matlab gives the following:

```
(1)
```

A =

```
1     1     0    -1
0    -1     1     2
-1    -1     0     0
0     0     0     0


jordan(A)
ans =

 0     1     0     0
 0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0
```

Now to find the full set of vectors:

You get one vector from : (same as in your question)

```
[V,D] = eig(sym(A))

V =

-1
1
1
0


D =

[ 0, 0, 0, 0]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

and follow the steps in the link below:

[Finding generalized Eigenvectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672408/generalized-eigenvectors-in-matlab)

For theory, refer to the download links for notes present on this link:

[Nilpotent Matrices/Jordan canonical form](http://clweb.csa.iisc.ernet.in/achintya/la2014/)

The idea of JCF comes from theory of Nilpotent matrices. (Annihilators)

Comment: Giving Matlab (or any other software output) nearly always defeats the purpose of answering a question here on MSE. @Bernard's answer above/below is the kind of thing we're looking for.